# How do I discover the IIS account under which an ASP.Net application is running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I need to ensure that when a C# (.Net 4.6.2) ASP.Net application starts it has a local folder available in its root folder to which it can write temporary data. I can get the application to create the folder if it doesn't exist, but how do I ascertain which IIS account the application was installed under? (I have no control over this and want to ensure that only that account has the necessary permissions). Mostly this will be a application pool identity, but sometimes not.

TIA

Comment: Do you have screen/admin access to the IIS server, or IIS manager permissions?

Comment: I need to do it programmatically. The code needs to create the folder and set the necessary security for the IIS account under which it is running. By definition it won't have admin rights - it is a web application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to get the identity (account) that the process is running-as in IIS.  Probably the easiest is `Request.ServerVariables()`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx

```
//I think this is the one you are asking about
Request.ServerVariables("APP_POOL_ID");
//if your request is not anonymous
Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER");
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_USER");
```

Otherwise, if you are using an authenticated (non-anonymous) asp.net page, you can get a lot more information from `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent`

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi;
wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var sid = wi.User.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I won't know the app pool ID - customers can choose their own app pool, and the request may be anonymous and may not.

Comment: So, what if you had a page called diagnostic.aspx, and in that page, you simply displayed the value from my first suggestion `APP_POOL_ID`?  Would that get you the info that you need?

Comment: No - it has to be done programmatically, silently get the value and use it. No user intervention.